# How to Validate Against Current User in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    #: First and last name do not cover name patterns around the globe
    username = CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    full_name = TitleCharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Scenario is same user cannot be a user and referred by user.
what I have done so far is

```
def clean(self):
    if self == self.referred_by:
        raise DjangoValidationError({'referred_by': _('Same user cannot be referred by user')})
```

I don't feel I am doing right what shall I do?

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear what you want to achieve...

Comment: suppose I have saved one user name 'X' and same user 'X' cannot be  used it in referred by field.

Comment: The two things I would change is `self.pk == self.referred_by_id`, and of course call the `super().clean()` if it does not raise an error, but for the rest, it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it slightly more efficient by cleaning this with the primary key of the `referred_by`, since that avoids an extra query. Furthermore you should call the `super().clean()` such that validations on parent class(es) are also performed, and you can also try to enforce this at the database side with [Django's *constraint framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import F, Q

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # …
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk == self.referred_by_id:
            raise ValidationError('Can not refer to itself!')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=~Q(pk=F('referred_by_id')),
                name='age_gte_18'
            )
        ]
```